# How to make for with arrays [Value and file name] and write first value for first file etc

Tags: bash

Iam trying to write some values for a file I have thiscode:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

value[0]=5.85
value[1]=3.87
value[2]=4.35

names_files=( EU EUA PT )

date="08-03-2020"

for i in "${value[@]}"
do
        for x in "${names_files[@]}"
        do
        echo "$date|$i" >> ./teste2/$x.dat
        done
done
```

But this writes me every values on first file! And I want to make this, to do first value to first file, second value for second file etc! How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through the indices of both the arrays.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

value[0]=5.85
value[1]=3.87
value[2]=4.35

names_files=( EU EUA PT )

date="08-03-2020"

for i in "${!value[@]}"; do
  echo "$date|${value[$i]}" > ./teste2/${names_files[$i]}.dat
done
```